# is it bad convention to call sys.argv from somewhere besides main function in python

Tags: python

I am writing a script and I have a function, call it `f()`, that needs one of the command line arguments (a filename it needs to open). However, `f()` is not called directly in the main function.

I was wondering if it was bad coding convention to call `sys.argv[1]` straight from `f()`? If I don't I would have to pass it as an argument to all of the functions that eventually call `f()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be a bad practice to always assume that the arguments that your function needs are available on the command-line - what if this code was invoked in some other manner?

A function should declare input parameters for the data it needs to access.

At the very least, passing the necessary argument into `f()` rather than accessing `sys.argv` helps make `f()` much more re-usable.

Answer (score 4):

It is bad form to access `sys.argv` from anywhere other than your main routine since it couples that code to the command line, making it difficult to use from other Python scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the file name into `f()`. This way, if you want to use that function later (as a module function, perhaps), you aren't bound to use `sys.argv`.

You could always make a wrapper to `f()` (if you are lazy or want to keep your 'main' code clean), that does something like:

```
def wrapperf():
    return f(sys.argv[1])
```

You could define `wrapperf` inside of `main()` if you want to keep it away from other scripts importing your module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be bad practice to access sys.argv from f.

I would  suggest passing the neccessary arguments into f. But since f won't neccessarily be called from main...maybe use a global variable? I normally try to avoid them, but in your case... >.>

I guess it would help to know a little more info about the way the program is setup. :P

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting the file name once, from sys.argv[1] if it exists, or demand user input if it doesn't.  Then store it as part of an object, or a global variable.  That will prevent having to pass what is essentially a static string all over the place, once it is set.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to parse sys.argv in some low-level function. To avoid lots of parameter-passing, you could provide a helper-function called by `main()` that simply stores the filename into a static variable for later use by `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally advise against it, but BaseHttpServer in python actually uses sys.argv[1] to determine which port to listen on. Convenience maybe.